# Powershell Animation Till the last command

Tags: powershell

- My Script has a lot of commands that taking time.
- How to make powershell animation till the last commands runs. I don't want start-sleep
- I tried Wait-Job but not working.
- I just got this function and it uses Start-sleep I can change it if it will affect

```
function ProcessingAnimation($scriptBlock) {
    $cursorTop = [Console]::CursorTop
    
    try {
        [Console]::CursorVisible = $false
        
        $counter = 0
        $frames = '|', '/', '-', '\' 
        $jobName = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
    
        while($jobName.JobStateInfo.State -eq "Running") {
            $frame = $frames[$counter % $frames.Length]
            
            Write-Host "$frame" -NoNewLine
            [Console]::SetCursorPosition(0, $cursorTop)
            
            $counter += 1
            Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 125
        }
        
        # Only needed if you use a multiline frames
        Write-Host ($frames[0] -replace '[^\s+]', ' ')
    }
    finally {
        [Console]::SetCursorPosition(0, $cursorTop)
        [Console]::CursorVisible = $true
    }
}
Write-Host "Getting System Information..."
ProcessingAnimation { Wait-Job -Name $WindowsVer }
command1
command2
command3
command4
command5
command6
$WindowsVer = (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion").ReleaseId
```

Comment: you could put it in a loop - updating the spinner once per loop. \\\\\ _however_ ... you are slowing your code when you add such stuff. i would just output a counter as text ... and use `Write-Verbose` or `Write-Information` since those are both OFF by default and can be toggled ON when you really want that. [*grin*]

Comment: You are supposed to pass the commands that take time through the `-scriptBlock` argument of the function: `ProcessingAnimation { command1; command2; ... }`. Are these commands under your control? I would rather let them output what they are currently doing instead of showing such a non-informative animation. If these are PowerShell commands you can usually pass `-Verbose` to get more informative output.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify why, specifically, you'd like to avoid `Start-Sleep`. You _can_ use `Wait-Job` as an alternative - just use it with `-Timeout` to periodically interrupt waiting in order to update the animation. Also consider passing all your commands in a _single_ script block (`{ ... }`) to `ProcessingAnimation`